# iOS Upload Video with video information GTLServiceYoutube

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, youtube, youtube-data-api

i want to upload video to youtube channel.i tried with following Code.the bellow code work to upload video but the problem is, i can't attach its information(Video Title,Description & Tags).after uploading it shows only video title as a "unknown" and no tags or description .
i've seen [CodingTofu](http://www.codingtofu.com/post/68053276589/posting-video-to-youtube) , [Dev7Dev Blog- iOS Sample Code](http://dev7dev.blogspot.in) and many other Q&A but i can't understand where i'm making mistake.

```
    NSString* title = video.title;
    NSString* description = video.videoDescription;
    NSData* data = video.data;
    NSMutableArray* tags = video.tags.mutableCopy;

    GTLYouTubeVideo *yVideo = [GTLYouTubeVideo object];
    GTLYouTubeVideoSnippet *snippet = [GTLYouTubeVideoSnippet alloc];
    snippet.title = title;
    snippet.descriptionProperty = description;

    [tags addObject:DEFAULT_KEYWORD];
    NSString* tag = [UploadController generateKeywordFromPlaylistId:UPLOAD_PLAYLIST];
    [tags addObject:tag];
    snippet.tags = tags;

    GTLYouTubeVideoStatus *status = [GTLYouTubeVideoStatus alloc];
    status.privacyStatus = @"public";

    GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:@"video/*"];
    GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForVideosInsertWithObject:yVideo part:@"snippet,status" uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
    service.uploadProgressBlock = ^(GTLServiceTicket* ticket, unsigned long long totalBytesUploaded, unsigned long long totalBytesExpectedToUpload){
        CGFloat percentage = totalBytesUploaded/totalBytesExpectedToUpload;
        NSLog(@"\nUploaded percentage %%(%0.2f)",percentage);
    };
    [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLYouTubeVideo *insertedVideo, NSError *error) {
            //[waitIndicator dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
            if (error == nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"File ID: %@", insertedVideo.identifier);

                return;
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);

                return;
            }
        }];
```

tell me if you need any further Details
thank you.

 sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the Mistake,
in above code, i have to add

```
GTLYouTubeVideo *yVideo = [GTLYouTubeVideo object];
GTLYouTubeVideoStatus *status = [GTLYouTubeVideoStatus alloc];
GTLYouTubeVideoSnippet *snippet = [GTLYouTubeVideoSnippet alloc];
*******
*******
*******
yVideo.snippet = snippet;//This part i forgot to add in my code
yVideo.status = status;//This part i forgot to add in my code
[service executeQuery........
```

This Might be helpful to someone who facing same issue.

Comment: Hi @Vatsal Shukla, can you tell me which pods libraries required for this task ?